# How to let django access virtualenv script?

Tags: python, django

1. I setup django in normal env and running python 2.7
2. I installed one module in different virtualenv and python 3.4

When I try to use script (which uses module inside virtualenv) I get:

> No module named `MyModule`

I am not sure if this makes much sense, but is it possible to make django use source bin/activate or something in order to use the script ?

Edit: Trying to make it work like this, but still gives error:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import sys
sys.path.append("/root/scrape/env/lib/python3.4")
from scraper import basic_usage   

def view_fun(request):
    basic_usage()
    return Response
```

I think problem is because it needs virtualenv to be activated, correct? Under error details it displays correct path:

```
Python Path:    
['/home/django/django_project',
 '/home/django',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 **'/root/scrape/env/lib/python3.4',
 '/root/scrape/env/lib/python3.4',
 '/root/scrape/env/lib/python3.4',
 '/root/scrape/env/lib/python3.4',**
```

Comment: Er, no. Install the script inside the same virtualenv.

Comment: it needs the settings module and all modules in the same virtualenv. why don't you create a django command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a module from a different python environment. That's the whole point of having python environments - that they are isolated.
Even if you managed to do so, the fact that you're talking about two different python version (2.7 / 3.4) will most probably make even the simplest module not work.

Why not just install Django and the module in the same virtualenv? you don't even need a special OS privilege to do so.